# How to capture video from webcam and feed it to my Yolov5 trained model(in PyTorch) inside a web app(inside the browser)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, yolo

I am working on a pothole detection system, and I have trained my model using Yolov5(by Ultralytics, completely implemented in PyTorch). After training the model in Google Colab, I have the final weight file in the **.pt format**. Now what I want to do is make some kind of web app which will take input from the webcam and feed it to my model in realtime. I searched a lot but didn't find a satisfying solution.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is no web app open source for this. But you can modify the ultralitycs detect.py to make a detector, put the information of your detection on a database and use it to show it on a web page.

https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/detect.py

Answer (score 0):

YOLOv5 provides the simple command to do so.
The command is:-

```
python detect.py --weights 'your-path-to-weights-file' --conf any-confidence-percentage-you-like --source 0
```

The above command is used if you run it on your local computer.